# 301 redirect http to https with www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, http-status-code-301

I have to redirect my domain from **http** to **https**. In my htaccess I have already.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This snippet redirect everything without "www" to "www".

When I change this to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**The result is:**

```
http://www.example.com/folder/page.php

becomes

Location => https://www.example.com/folder/page.php
```

**Fine!**

```
https://example.com/folder/page.php

becomes

https://www.example.com/folder/page.php
```

**Fine!**

**but:**

```
 http://example.com/folder/page.php

 becomes

 Location => https://example.com/folder/page.php
```

**but it has to be**

```
 Location => https://www.example.com/folder/page.php
```

How is it possible to fix this?

I know all of this redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1   [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but I need only one redirection instead of two 301.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{RERUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: thanks for your help. This gives a 500 Server Error, thanks for fixing this

Comment: Ok, you fixed ths 500 Server error but now https://example.com/folder/page.php becomes to https://example.com

Comment: @Labu77 Please clear your browser caches and make sure you dont have any other redirect rules.

Comment: I checked it many times, but every page is redirecting to the startpage. I check it with http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php, so I have no caching errors

Comment: @labu77 do you have another .htaccess in /folder?

Comment: there is no second htaccess in the root folder. However, I found a working solution. Will puplishe this solution here. Thank you very much for your time and effort for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/84757/htaccess-redirect-non-www-to-www-with-ssl-https

The second answer by @w3dk is working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

*Your site needs to be accessible by both www and non-www over SSL for the .htaccess redirect to trigger.*

With letsencrypt its no problem to have this 2 certs.

Comment: There is no diffrence between my answer and the answer you provided. Are you sure my code failed ?

Comment: yes, I checked it twice and now again. your code made a redirect to the startpage. thank you.

Comment: Its really wired.